# Gurobi Python Accessible constraints for derived variables

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, gurobi

I'm implementing a MILP in Gurobi using Python. My problem has several variables that are derived from decision variables, such as:

[image: y]

With `d[tau]` being a constant value and `q[t,tau,k]` being a binary decision variable. To make the notation clearer, I want to reuse these variables later, for example in the objective or in constraints. I'm not sure on how to implement it correctly. Being new to Gurobi, my approach is as follows:

1. I declare `y[t,tau,k]` as a variable using `Model.addVar()`
2. I create an equality constraint to enforce `y[t,tau,k]=q[t,tau,k]*d[tau]` using `Model.addConstr()`

In code:

```
y[t,tau,k] = dda_prob_IS.addVar(
    lb=0.0,
    vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS,
    name=f'y[{t},{tau},{k}]')

dda_prob_IS.addConstr(
    y[t,tau,k] == q[t,tau,k]*d[tau],
    name = f'y_def[{t},{tau},{k}]')
```

I'm exclusively using `y[t,tau,k]` in the following parts of the implementation, hence I need to be able to access a particular `y`. Is there a more elegant way to implement this or is my approach even correct?

Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addVars()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html) to create these variables more efficient:

```
y = dda_prob_IS.addVar(len(T), len(Tau), len(K)    
    lb=0.0,
    vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)
```

This creates a tupledict that you can access using the 3 indices.

You can also use [addConstr()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html) to add multiple similar constraints at once by looping over your variables inside the call.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using `addVars()`, I was just breaking my problem down for the question here. Still, I',m unsure if the way I'm doing it is the proper procedure to model my derived variables?

Comment: I don't see another, easier or somehow better approach.